# Liferay customized portlet without hook

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

How can I make a customized login portlet that redirects the user into his own Liferay page without using hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you don't need to change anything in Liferay's authentication - at least you shouldn't make this your first option. This is a common question with many different answers. Instead of prescribing one of them (I probably wouldn't find the correct option to your one-line-question anyway), I'd like you to search for "default landing page" or "custom landing page" in Liferay.

This will give you a lot of ideas how to solve this problem - from a simple configuration change to a ready-to-go app on Liferay's marketplace. And many more. Choose what applies to your situation.

Sorry that this is quite unspecific, but your question doesn't give a lot of details to work with, so I'm assuming it's best to give a pointer to all the options - you'll just have to know the relevant search terms.